# Architecture alternatives to solve large table issues in Postgres 9.0

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch

We use PostgreSQL 9.0 for our application and there is a table called `events` with a lot of metadata columns about event itself. The most important is `resource_id` that tells for which `resource` is related.

This table has being growing a lot and currently stores only `6 months` of data. Its `table_size` is `~200 GB` with `456 millions` rows.

To optimize our most common searches we have two indexes:

- `timestamp`
- `timestamp` with `resource_id`

These indexes are used frequently and its size is `~160 GB`.

This scenario that I've described is happening in a single `Master` instance without `Slaves` servers nor sharding.

Now we intend to extend this period from `6 months` to `5 years` of data. Estimating this amount in data would be something about `~4 billions` rows with a `table_size` about `~ 2 TB` of data.

So our indexes will have something about `1.6 TB` (which I'm really worried to run in a single instance).

We had some ideas to improve this such as:

- Remove indexes from table and store all that data in database focused in `Data warehousing` and indexing all this data in an `ElasticSearch` cluster
- Remove index from table, indexing data in an `ElasticSearch` but with only ID in its body. So I would only use `ElasticSearch` to search and database to retrieve this data
- Give a try in `InfluxDB` (time-series database), filtering and selecting data from all this `5 years` directly from it
- Upgrade PostgreSQL to `9.6`, clusterize (Master + 2 Slaves) and/or partitioning

We're looking for scalable solutions that proper solves this scenario best-way possible. Thoughts?

Comment: I don't see any reason to shard this data.  What you definitely _can_ do is partitioning.  Events are usually so that the most recent ones are the most interesting, and older ones are queried increasingly less often.  Upgrading to 9.6 is definitely a good idea - BRIN indexes, for example, might be useful.  If there is a subset of metadata that you need way more often than the others, it might also make sense to split your table vertically, moving the less often viewed data into a separate table.

Comment: @dezso didn't know about BRIN indexes, maybe it could be a solution. About sharding I confused when writing, already fixed, really meant `partitioning`

Comment: Why have an index on both `timestamp` and `(timestamp, resource_id)` ?  Dropping the single-column index would cut the size dedicated to indexes nearly in half.

Comment: Split up your giant event table into lots of small ones. Monthly or weekly tables - and the use constraint partitioning by time-stamp https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html

Comment: @jjanes we use both indexes to query events by `timestamp` and combined (`timestamp` + `resource_id`).

@maxTrialfire we already considered splitting by timestamp, thanks for contributing :D